# How to reference a SBT Setting from a different module in a multi-module build

Tags: sbt

In a multi-module build with a sub module `server` I have written a custom task in `server/build.sbt` in which I would like to reference the `baseDirectory` of the root project. Here is the task:

```
lazy val genData = taskKey[Unit]("generate files")

genData := {
    List(
        Generator(baseDirectory.value.getParentFile, (resourceDirectory in Compile).value)
    ).foreach(_.makeData())
}
```

Instead of `baseDirectory.value.getParentFile` I would like to write somehing like `(baseDirectory in root).value` but this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```scala
(baseDirectory in LocalRootProject).value
```