# How to reference a custom SBT Setting in sub-projects

Tags: scala, sbt

Somewhat similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780485/how-to-reference-a-sbt-setting-from-a-different-module-in-a-multi-module-build), how can reference a **custom** setting in a sub project.

In build.sbt:

```
import sbt.Keys._

val finagleVersion = settingKey[String]("Defines the Finagle version")

val defaultSettings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
  finagleVersion in ThisBuild := "6.20.0",
  organization in ThisBuild := "my.package",      
  scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.4",
  version in ThisBuild := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
)

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(thrift).settings(
  publishArtifact in (Compile, packageBin) := false,
  publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false,
  publishArtifact in (Compile, packageSrc) := false
)

lazy val thrift = project.in(file("thrift"))
```

In thrift/build.sbt:

```
name := "thrift"

// doesn't work
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-thriftmux" % (finagleVersion in LocalRootProject).value
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.sbt` files cannot see the definitions (e.g., `val`s) in other `.sbt` files, even if they are part of the same build.

However, all `.sbt` files in a build can see/import the content of `project/*.scala` files. So you'll have to declare your `val finagleVersion` in a `.scala` file:

`project/CustomKeys.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object CustomKeys {
  val finagleVersion = settingKey[String]("Defines the Finagle version")
}
```

Now, in your `.sbt` files, just

```
import CustomKeys._
```

and you're good to go.